# Verdaccio access from internet

Tags: node.js, packaging, serve

I can't access the Verdaccio page from the internet.

I have the right IP address since I can serve a minimalist webpage and access it through the internet (with serve, port 5000) but as soon as I use the same IP address (in Chrome) with the Verdaccio port (4873) instead of the serve port, it does not work. It behaves as if the IP is wrong.

Do I need to do something specific to access the Verdaccio page? I would like to have access to it in order to see all the packages I have in my private registry.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your configuration?

Comment: I found finally the solution, you need to put the `listen` information in the config file like this `listen: 0.0.0.0:4873` and then it works, it is set to `localhost` by default

Comment: Cool. Please would be great if you answer your self for future references :)

Comment: The answer is also in verdaccio website https://www.verdaccio.org/docs/en/configuration.html#listen-port

Comment: But why is it made accessible from `0.0.0.0` and not from `localhost` by default ? I see it's the case with the Docker image as well.

Answer (score 3):

*in config.yaml:*

```
listen:
  - 'localhost:2020'
```

*change to*

```
listen:
  - '0.0.0.0:2020'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found finally the solution, you need to put the listen information in the config file like this listen: 0.0.0.0:4873 and then it works, it is set to localhost by default !

Comment: You can host it to get it publically accessible. Refer here if you need more info:
https://medium.com/admitkard/verdaccio-hosting-your-own-private-npm-registry-e1a94d3521fd